# hammer.js and SVG interactivity

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg, hammer.js

i'm having a problem using hammer.js and an SVG file. It seems that the svg does not react on inputs by hammer. Here is my problem narrowed down in a code-example:

html-snippet:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="background: blue">
    <h1>My div</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <object id="mysvg" data="circle.svg"/>
</div>    
<script>
    var element_div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var element_svg = document.getElementById('mysvg');

    Hammer(element_div).on("tap", function(event){
        console.log("tap div");
    });

    Hammer(element_svg).on("tap", function(event){
        console.log("svg tap");
    });
</script>
```

svg-snippet:

```
<circle id="bubble" fill="black" stroke="#0000ff" cx="50" cy="50" r="50">
<set attributeName="fill" to="yellow" begin="click" />
</circle>
```

Using the "object"-tag to load the svg file into html, i can use the "onclick" event of SVG to change the color, but hammer won't see the circle and doesn't log the "svg tap". It logs the "tap div" above perfectly though, so hammer works as intended.

An alternative would be to use the "img src"-tag to load the svg file into html. Then, i can "hammer" on the object (it logs the text), but the color won't switch.

Problem: I need both things to work, hammer-multitouch as well as svg-interactivity... Is there another way to load the file so hammer can interact with it and the SVG-interactivity won't get lost?
Thx for your help :)

Comment: Why not have the svg inline instead of including it via tags.

Comment: It's supposed to be a really big SVG-File of a big Subway-Plan, that would totally mess my html up - thats why i didn't really consider it, seems to work on this small example though... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an AJAX loader to load the picture and put it inline. Remember not to add the event listeners before the picture is loaded.

Here is an example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/VPc9m/1/

```
$('#mysvg').load("https://rawgit.com/VengadoraVG/moving-to-gnulinux/master/img/tux.svg",
function (response, status, xhr) {
    Hammer(document.getElementById("layer1")).on("tap", function(event){
    alert("svg-layer1 tap");
    });

    Hammer(document.getElementById("path3889")).on("tap", function(event){
    alert("svg-path3889 tap");
    });
});
```

Note: the tag with id "mysvg" is declared in the way below:

```
<div id="mysvg">
</div>
```

Comment: This looks quite promising, though i don't get the right alerts in your js-fiddle; In Firefox, i get the "svg-layer1 tap", even if i click on the nose. When i click the nose in Chrome, i first get the "svg-layer1 tap" and then the "svg-path3889 tap". Clicking the rect outside, nothnig happens (though, as i see it, nothing should). Or did you mean the blue div? I surely get that alert. Will try this in my code and see what will happen. Thx for the answer :)

Comment: Alright, so i marked this as accepted because it kinda works - its not perfect though. If I will find a better way, I'm going to post it here. Thx anyway :)

Comment: Can break relative URIs in the SVG file, but best solution so far, +1